# Compare index of 2 elements in a collection

Tags: html, vba

**Issue :** I have some issues figuring out a way to select elements in my HTMLDocument which are under a certain point in the page.

In the following code sample, as you can see in the comments, I first select a part of them which respect my queryselector criteria

```
IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")
```

In this example I have 10 elements in this collection. Each of this element in contained in a table which is its parent on the 7th degree.

```
MsgBox TypeName(IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")(2).ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode) ' HTMLTable
```

Some of those elements are in the same table.

You can see here the form which contains all the tables  [image: the form which contains all the tables].

Now, the thing is that I want to select the innerHTML of some of those elements only and not all of them. The criterion to know if I one of those 10 elements interests me or not is it's position on the webpage. I want all the elements which are under the message *Part Usage*. There is only one table containing the *Part Usage* text and so my idea was to see if the table in which are contained each element has a higher or lower index in the "form" collection.
If the index is higher I want this element, otherwise I discard it.

What I did for this is the following code :

1. I set the ID *Bim* to all the tables containing one or more
   from the 10 elements.

   ```
    For Each Element In IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']") ' here for all of the 10 numbers found with the  queryselectorall we'll find their respective table in the collection (form) and set its Class as "Bim". But since some of the numbers are in the same table, we won't have 10 tables with a classname "Bim" at the end of the process. We'll have only x tables with the classname "Bim"



   Element.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.Class = "Bim"

   Next
   ```
2. I set the ID *Stop* to the table containing the text *Part Usage*

   ```
   For Each Element In IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("SectionHead")

       If Element.innerHTML = "Part Usage" Then

          'MsgBox TypeName(Element.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode)' HTMLTable
          Element.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ID = "Stop"

       End If

    Next
   ```
3. I check which tables with the Classname *Bim* are under (=higher index) the table with the ID *Stop*. For the table ( there is actually only one) matching the criterion of point 3 I apply  `IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")` inside of them so that I get all the elements in contains and more paricularly their innerHTML.

   ```
                                    For Each Element In IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("Bim") ' Here we check all the x tables which have the Classname "Bim"


       If Element.indexInTheWholeForm > IEDoc.getElementById("Stop").indexInTheWholeForm Then 'and compare somehow if their index in the (form) collection if higher than the table with the ID "Stop" ( this is similar to checking if the element if lower on the webpage in thic case) ( we only want the element which have a higher index aka under the Part Usage table)

              For Each Element2 In Element.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']") ' Now we are in the table which contains the part numbers and we'll look for all the part numbers it contains by applying the queryselectorall again, but this time only in this specific table

                     array_parts2(iteration2) = Element.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")(iteration2).innerHTML

                    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iteration2 + 1, 19) = array_parts2(iteration2)

                    iteration2 = iteration2 + 1
               Next

       End If
       Next
   ```

of course what doesn't work is the *indexInTheWholeForm* property which doesn't exist. Any ideas on how to do this ?

Thank for reaching that line :)

Comment: `getElementById` is supposed to only return one element, because Id is supposed to be unique across the whole page: if you're setting the same Id for multiple elements then that's not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah of course you're right I didn't even notice this mistake. If I use the same method but with the name instead then, would you have any idea on how to fix this index issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I would do something like this (assuming I understood you correctly)

```
Sub Tester()

    Const S_MATCH As String = "td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']"

    Dim e, tbl, bHit As Boolean

    '...
    'load page etc
    '...


    'get all the matching rows and cycle though them
    For Each e In IEDoc.querySelectorAll(S_MATCH)

        'did we get to the table of interest yet?
        If Not bHit Then
            Set tbl = e.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode. _
                        ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode
            If IsPartUsageTable(tbl) Then bHit = True
        End If

        If bHit Then
            'we reached the table of interest, so
            '  do something with e
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Function IsPartUsageTable(tbl) As Boolean
    Dim e, rv As Boolean
    For Each e In tbl.getElementsByClassName("SectionHead")
        If Element.innerHTML = "Part Usage" Then
            rv = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    IsPartUsageTable = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your solution, but it's not really what I was looking for, maybe I wasn't clear enough. With  `IEDoc.querySelectorAll(S_MATCH)` I select a bunch of elements and each of those have a table as a 7th parent degree. Those tables are in form (see picture). Then I have to see if the table they are in is higher or lower ( in term of index) than the table containing the _Part Usage_ text. If their table has a higher index ( = under in the list) then I keep those elements. Also I editted my code above in term of the ID issue, I replaced it with class.

Comment: OK my code tests for whether they are in the "Part Usage" table or beyond: you could adapt it to only process those rows *beyond* that table (not in and beyond)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as unexpected as it sounds, I think I found a solution to my own question. I will confirm you that it works as soon as I have the possibility to run it with my colleague. 
So I keep point 1 and 2 from my initial post and I replaced point 3 with the following :

```
For i = 0 To IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).getElementsByTagName("table").length 
          If IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(i).ID = "Stop" Then
                index_Part_Usage = i
                Position_Part_Usage = index + 1
                Exit For
           End If
      Next
       'MsgBox Position_Part_Usage






      For i = 0 To IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).getElementsByTagName("table").length
          If IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(i).className = "Bim" Then
                index = i
                Position = index + 1
                If index > index_Part_Usage Then
                    For Each Element2 In IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(i).querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']") ' Now we are in the table which contains the part numbers and we'll look for all the part numbers it contains by applying the queryselectorall again, but this time only in this specific table

                        array_parts2(iteration2) = IEDoc.getElementsByTagName("form")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(i).querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")(iteration2).innerHTML

                         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iteration2 + 1, 19) = array_parts2(iteration2)

                        iteration2 = iteration2 + 1
                    Next
                End If
           End If
      Next i
```