# Internet Explorer randomly crashing

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to run a macro that goes on an HTML document on a webpage. The code seems ok, but I can't even make sure of it since Internet Explorer crashes all the time before the end of it. You can see here the first part of my code ( a bigger sample of it is on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682968/compare-index-of-2-elements-in-a-collection/40699815?noredirect=1#comment68679462_40699815)).

```
For Each Element In IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']") '
    Element.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.className = "Bim" ' instead of ID
Next


For Each Element In IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("SectionHead")
    If Element.innerHTML = "Part Usage" Then
        'MsgBox TypeName(Element.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode)' HTMLTable
        Element.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ID = "Stop"
    End If
Next
```

The first weak spot seems to be just at the end of the first For loop, right after it passes this step.

This [image: error message] is being displayed and of course the code can't keep running since I am still extracting data from the HTML webpage document.

Any ideas on how to prevent this crash ?

What I did so far is to call some of the following functions in the loop but it didn't make any difference.

```
Sub Timers()

    Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
    PauseTime = 0.2    ' Set duration.
    Start = Timer    ' Set start time.
    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes.
    Loop
    'Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
    'TotalTime = Finish - Start    ' Calculate total time.
    'MsgBox "Paused for " & TotalTime & " seconds"
End Sub

Public Sub Warte_mal()
    'Workaround to get the overview page in PuMA opened
    Dim WshShell
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.popup "Overview page will be opened", 1, "Have some patience...."

End Sub


Sub WaitIE(ie As InternetExplorer)
    Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to fully load the web page in IE?

Comment: Yes, actually the first part of the code which I didn't show here consists in going on the webpage, entering some datas in a form and clicking on a "search" button to display more information. This first part works without problem. I can show it if you think it might help, but the webpage is an intranet.

Comment: You say the code is crashing randomly.  Does that mean it is not always the same line?  If so do the crashing lines have anything in common, for example, does it always crash when updating the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)?

Comment: Yes I said random because at first when I opened the document I was able to go through those 2 first for loops I showed here with no problem but it crashed after the second one. So I ran the code again and now it always crashes after the first loop, so it s not always on the same line. I don't know if this might come from the type of variable for internet ( I tried Object, New InternetExplorer or SHDocVw.InternetExplorer) but no differences. It never crashes before the end of that first loop though, so DOM has been updated but when I go through its new content crash occurs

Comment: I just tried from an other computer and it crashes inside on the first loop, some before the end of it...really strange and if I run it with F8 step-by-step I can go a bit further before internet crashes

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION : I found a way to avoid Internet Explorer to crash but I don't fully understand why it does work this way and not the other one.

What I did is to replace the first *For Each* loop by a For iteration loop.

```
longueur = IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']").length - 1

 For i = 0 To longueur

 IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")(i).ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.className = "Bim"

    Next i
```

I can understand that looking for the 7th parent of an element might be a heavy operation but I still don't understand why it works this way and not with the *For Each* loop.